# Could an x-ray tube be made to emit other kinds of EM radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, x-rays

If the accelerating voltage of an x-ray tube is greatly reduced, could it be made to emit photons of lower energy (UV or visible)?

Comment: EM radiation of lower frequencies than X-rays,  including infra-red, are emitted from the target but very little if any escape through the beryllium window.

Answer (score 0):

To make an x-ray you have to strike the atom with an electron that has enough energy to penetrate deep into the electron cloud and knock one of those electrons completely out of its orbital. Lower energy impacts (from the electrons in an electron beam) cannot penetrate deeply enough to  kick out one of the deep electrons and hence x-rays will not be produced.

Comment: I probably should have clarified this in my question, but I was thinking of bremsstrahlung emissions and not characteristic x-rays